# Secure login procedure

Tags: tls, authentication

I have implemented a login, and session, procedure for a web app and I am wondering whether what I have implemented is secure enough.
The authentication is based on login password on https. If the login succeeded the server returns a randomly generated token the server stores and sends with any https post request it makes. The server verifies the received token is the one generated for that userid. 
The token has a timeout.
Is this procedure secure enough? what weaknesses does it have?

**UPDATE**
the problem is that it seems sessions are not supported  by mobile applications (i.e. Android, iOS) and I have had to develop my own kind of sessions. However I am a bit afraid it is not secure enough.

Comment: You essentially describe OAuth2 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth#OAuth_2.0, and is pretty standard across web applications.

Comment: This is just an session/authentication cookie. Don't reinvent the wheel :)

Comment: the problem is that it seems sessions are not supported  by mobile applications (i.e. Android, iOS) and I have had to develop my own kind of sessions. However I am a bit afraid it is not secure enough.

Comment: Are you sure the **server** stores and sends that? Is it generated by a CSRNG?

Answer (score 0):

Your login system seems good enough to provide basic authentication control, as you are describing an standard cookie-based HTTP authentication system.

But anyway, the *best* recommendation is: It's always better trying to use an standard, as the main security concern relating custom-made authentication/authorization systems is usually the implementation. You should try to avoid implementing your own authentication methods when you have an alternative.

So, if you are using any framework for developing your application, try to use the authentication methods provided by it !